# I need to make a usb port to be dumb to any devices newly connected

Tags: usb, power-management

Could anyone help me with my trouble with usb?
It sounds ridiculous probably but I need to make one of usb ports do not answer to any devices programmatically. But I need the port to continue provide power. I have some device which need to charge from usb power sometime and sometime to interact to it as normal. Now once I connect this device to my PC (which is really a CarPC) I see a menu that provide only two items to choose: file storage or webcam. And if I choose one of these items I won't get access to the main menu until the device is powered off and on without a usb cable. But I need the device to be connected to PC permanently... If I just unbind the device programmatically (echo "1-3" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind) - it won't help - there will be storage or webcam modes until power is off or the reset key is pressed. But after reset it prompts for choosing one of the connection modes to PC. So I need to prevent usb port to make "handshaking" to my device. And another time turn the port to normal mode. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a charge-only USB adapter:
[https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Universal-Charge-Only-Adapter-Android/dp/B00FA9GXKM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FA9GXKM)
or something like it.
There are also other types of these charge-only adapters that will negotiate charge voltage, but not allow the two devices to connect. Or you could use a charge only usb cable to connect the device.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I need to connect this device to PC permanently and use it  for charging while I use webcam or file storage mode and for standalone device. So I need to operate programmatically.

Comment: @RomeNovikow You can remove it and plug in without adapter, there will be only a few seconds ago with no charging